# C Programming - integer value printing incorrectly

Tags: c, printf

I'm using Borland C v3.1 (DOS Version)

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void WTF()
{
    int array[15],i;
    int WTF_NUMBER=12345;

    for(i=0;i<16;i++) array[i]=0;

    printf("%d",WTF_NUMBER);
}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    WTF();
    getch();
}
```

I should get 12345 as output, but I'm getting 0 instead. Help.

Comment: `i<16` --> `i<15`

Comment: Just for clarification, array has elements numbered 0-14, when setting array[15] you're doing bad things to memory you don't own.

Comment: Stop wasting effort: `memset (array, 0, sizeof (array));` And the _first_ thing you should do is _stop_ using Borland, and get a compiler that's been kept up to date over the last twenty years :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect.

Instead of

`for(i=0;i<16;i++) array[i]=0;`

you should have

`for(i=0;i<15;i++) array[i]=0;`

since your array has only 15 elements.

Comment: Better is to use `sizeof(array)` instead of `15`.

Comment: @codemonkey 'wrong' isn't 'better'. It could be sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]), but too long to type.

Comment: You are right ;) However it doesn't matter if it's long. It is more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

You defined array "array" as having only 15 elements.

```
int array[15],i;
```

But in the loop below the definition you are trying to initialize 16 elements that is elements with indices 0 through 15 inclusively.

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++) array[i]=0;
```

So this loop overwrites ,memory occupied by variable  WTF_NUMBER that is array[15] occupies the same memory as WTF_NUMBER.

Write the loop like

```
for (i=0; i < 15; i++ ) array[i]=0;
```

Or you could simply define the array as

```
int array[15] = { 0 };
```

In this case all elements of the array would be initialized by 0.

Another way to initialize the array by zero is to use standard function memset

```
memset( array, 0, 15 * sizeof( int ) );
```

or

```
memset( array, 0, sizeof( array ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeded array boundary in `for` loop. SO make it as `for(i=0;i<15;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

`array` can hold 15 elements 0-14 should be your array index.

Accessing `array[15]` is out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

Your look is the wrong size, the array has 15 elements, the loop loops 16 times, it overwrites the end of the array and onto the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Program will crash due to invalid array size; change it to 15 in for loop and you will get desired output.

Comment: Unless your definition of crash is different to the norm, no. UB _may_ crash but it's by no means guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop
Try to initialize you array like this

```
int array[15] = {0};
```

I think you will get your desired output then.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve several issues by judicious use of the standard library. There's not really any need for you to do this in an explicit loop *at all:*

```
int array[15];
memset (array, 0 , sizeof (array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to wrong array size in for loop, the value of WTF-Number is over written.